# Embed youtube video height issue

Tags: html, css, youtube, embed, responsive

I'm trying to embed a youtube video into my project, it works and I also tried to apply a 16:9 ratio with `padding-bottom: 56.25%` like as most tutorials out there.

The issue is, the height of video is happened to be 100% of the container, What should I fix in my CSS to get rid of the top/bottom blackbar?

Here's my code pen attemp: https://codepen.io/DieByMacro/pen/QXmJez

```css
.HomePage-homeVideoWrapper-274 {
  height: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 720px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.HomePage-homeVideoWrapper-274 iframe {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="HomePage-homeVideoWrapper-274">
  <iframe height="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Qjmp2r2OsZ4" title="Home-admin tutorial" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Get rid of `height: 100%;` and see what happens? Or I recon you can change the height, if you want it something different.

Comment: @Chipster getting rid of `height: 100%` will make the video frame collapsed and having wrong ratio, I'm trying to achieve a fluid video container with max-width of 720px as you can see

Comment: Ah. I see. I get it now. What happens if you get rid of `height: 0;` in the other block instead?

Comment: Playing around a bit with it, you might want to look into adjusting the height--or, more accurately, the max-height--of your container div.

Comment: sure I did try to `max-height` the container, but funny that it doesnt affect the iframe

Comment: `padding-bottom: 24%` will fix the issue but I'm not sure why it works instead of `56.25%`, since 9/16 is .5625 or 56.25% ... so weird

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very common problem which we are facing while we add a videos on our template.You just need to add max-width and width property on **OUTER** div not at **HomePage-homeVideoWrapper-274**. No need to added **max-height** in HomePage-homeVideoWrapper-274.

```css
.outer {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.HomePage-homeVideoWrapper-274 {
    height: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
  
  iframe {
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
   <div class="HomePage-homeVideoWrapper-274">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Qjmp2r2OsZ4" title="Home-admin tutorial"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/Mak0619/pen/pXLYEK)